# how to implement import and export to xml file in grails application

Tags: sql-server, postgresql, grails, grails-2.3

I have two grails application one run in sql server 2008 grails version 1.2 and another application run in postgresql grails verison 2.3.8.
Now i want to import some data from old application to new ato pplication via application.I mean when user is in new application to be able to switch old application select some data may from list and import to new application?or create xlm and import to new application.

Can anyone help in any way how to do this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should consider using integration library like spring-integration or apache camel. You can read much more in description of this frameworks. I would not suggest implementing all transport, conversion, failover, etc. by yourself

Comment: You can export data from old application as in JSON or XML and then import them into new application with hassle free parsing in Grails XML or JSON parsing or dumping.